# Tem um jeito de fazer estas atribuições de forma mais limpa?

Tags: php, array, classes

Tenho uma classe que deve ser iniciada com um `array` de propriedades.

```
$subscription = new CheckRenew([
    'custom_2_id' => 13,
    'email'       => 'someemail@email.com',
    'zip'         => '90530000',
    'number'      => '1234' 
]);
```

Dentro dela possui um metodo `__construct()`, que define estes recursos. Porém, este `array` pode vir sem um dos elementos, então antes de atribuir eu verifico se existe cada elemento.

```
namespace App\SubscriptionHelpers;

use App\SubscriptionModels\Subscription;

class CheckRenew
{
    public $zip;
    public $email;
    public $addressNumber;
    protected $custom2Id; // service customer id (magento)

    public function __construct($info)
    {
        $this->custom2Id = null;
        if (isset($info['custom_2_id'])) {
            $this->custom2Id = $info['custom_2_id'];
        }

        $this->email = null;
        if (isset($info['email'])) {
            $this->email = $info['email'];
        }

        $this->email = null;
        if (isset($info['email'])) {
            $this->email = $info['email'];
        }

        $this->zip = null;
        if (isset($info['zip'])) {
            $this->zip = $info['zip'];          
        }

        $this->addressNumber = null;
        if (isset($info['number'])) {
            $this->addressNumber = $info['number'];         
        }
    }
}
```

Bem básico. E funciona, o problema é que como pode-se ver, eu repeti muito código. Como sou doente por DRY (don't repeat yourself), eu gostaria, se possível, que alguêm me ajudasse a achar um método mais limpo de fazer estas atribuições.

**TL;DR**

Eu gostaria de saber de um jeito mais limpo, clean, de checar e atribuir minhas prpriedades da classe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Por exemplo:*** faz um `foreach` varrendo o `array` e passando isso para as propriedades da sua classe de maneira dinâmica.

<sup>***Observação:*** as chaves do `array` tem que ter o mesmo nome do `itens` da classe</sup>

```
<?php

class CheckRenew
{
    public $zip;
    public $email;
    public $addressNumber;
    protected $custom2Id; 
    public function __construct($info)
    {
        foreach($info as $key => $value)
        {
            $this->$key = $value;
        }
    }
}


$subscription = new CheckRenew([
    'custom2Id' => 13,
    'email'       => 'someemail@email.com',
    'zip'         => '90530000',
    'addressNumber' => '1234' 
]);


var_dump($subscription);
```

*Observe que eu mudei dois nomes do array para ter o mesmo nome dos itens da sua classe.*

[***Exemplo Online***](http://ideone.com/tj2w3X)

---

***Adendo:***

Se passar algum nome errado, ou então, passar algum elemento que não esteja na classe automaticamente ele será adicionado no escopo dessa classe e será acessível.

***Exemplo:***

```
<?php

class CheckRenew
{
    public $zip;
    public $email;
    public $addressNumber;
    protected $custom2Id; 
    public function __construct($info)
    {
        foreach($info as $key => $value)
        {
            $this->$key = $value;
        }
    }
}


$subscription = new CheckRenew([
    'custom2Id' => 13,
    'email'       => 'someemail@email.com',
    'zip'         => '90530000',
    'addressNumber' => '1234',
    'all' => true 
]);


var_dump($subscription->all);
```

nesse exemplo mostra claramente que foi adicionado um item a mais a sua classe o `all` sendo ele publico e acessível. Só tem que tomar cuidado com esse tipo de acontecimento.

[***Exemplo Online***](http://ideone.com/exEAkC)

Comment: Wow, gostei da sua abordagem! Vou esperar apenas mais um pouco para ver se alguém aparece com uma solução tão boa quanto esta

Comment: @wdarking, ok !!! dá para melhorar mais, dá para checar o itens da classe, mas, esse modo é o mais simples possível. O bom desse modo é um padrão de nomes que pode facilitar no seu desenvolvimento.